# c# allocating memory to the virtual machine

Tags: c#

Does C# have an equivalent of java's -Xmx1024m switch that allows you to increase memory allocation to the virtual machine?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No.  The CLR handles memory allocation very differently than java in this regard.  It will continue to increase the heap size, with no upper limit (other than architectural limits).

On a 64bit Operating System, while targetting x64, the CLR will continue to allow a process to allocate memory up to the total memory available in the system.  There is no fixed upper limit artificially imposed on a process.

On a 32bit system, or when targetting x86, the practical upper limit tends to be between 1.2 and 1.6 GB.  At this point, you will start running into out of memory exceptions.  (Theoretically, it should use 2GB, but the CLR itself takes up some space, and the way it handles memory addressing causes the Out of memory errors to occur in this range instead.)

---

Edit: Here's a good article describing the [differences in how memory is handled in the JVM and the CLR](http://benpryor.com/blog/2006/05/04/jvm-vs-clr-memory-allocation/).  I believe the main reason the JVM requires the use of `-Xmx` is because it does not release memory back to the operating system.  It therefore provides a way to limit the memory consumption of a program.

Comment: Just one addition, even on x64 you are limited to a 2 GB Heap, even though your total address space can be a lot bigger: http://blogs.msdn.com/joshwil/archive/2005/08/10/450202.aspx

Comment: @Michael Stum: That's 2GB for a SINGLE OBJECT, not for the heap.  He was referring to the fact that you can't allocate a large array of structs, if the total size of the array will make an object larger than 2GB. I write software in C# that regularly uses much, much more than 2GB of memory on the heap.